# ¿Cómo procesar teclados en Arduino?

Tags: arduino, compilar

Estaba haciendo un programa en arduino utilizando vectores, una lcd 20x4 y un Keypad. El propósito el programa es simplemente que a través del Keypad se ingresen todos los números que se quieran (posteriormente mostrados en la LCD). En general no es nada fuera de este mundo, pero... cuando compilo el programa me aparece el mensaje"collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status exit status 1 Error compilando para la tarjeta Arduino Uno."
No había tenido este problema hasta hoy. (quiero compilar, exportar binarios y utilizarlos en una simulación en Proteus). Adjunto el código a continuación:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 10, en = 11, d4 = 12, d5 = 13, d6 = 14, d7 = 15;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs,en,d4,d5,d6,d7);
const byte filas = 4;
const byte columnas = 4;

byte pin_filas[] = {9,8,7,6};
byte pin_columnas[] = {};

char teclas [filas][columnas] =
{
   {'7','8','9','%'},
   {'4','5','6','x'},
   {'1','2','3','-'},
   {'C','0','=','+'}
};

Keypad teclado1 = Keypad(makeKeymap(teclas),pin_filas,pin_columnas,4,4);

void agrega(char pulso, char num, int i, int *c, void *a, void *b){
   i = i+1;
   b = realloc(c, i * sizeof(int));

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Ingresa un numero:");
  if(pulso != 0){
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(pulso);
  num = pulso;
  c[i] = num;
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("Guardado");
  delay(1500);
  }
}

void libera(int *c, void *a, void *b, int i){
if(a == NULL){
     lcd.setCursor(0,0);
     lcd.print("No hay espacio en la memoria");
     free(a);
     delay(1500);
     lcd.clear();
  }
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Datos ingresados");
  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
     lcd.setCursor(0,1);
     lcd.print(c[j]);
     lcd.print(", ");
     delay(50);
  }
delay(3500);
lcd.clear();
free(a);
free(b);
free(c);
}
void setup() {
int i;
char num;
void *a = NULL;
void *b = NULL;
int *c = NULL;
i = 1;
a = malloc(i * sizeof(int));

lcd.begin(20,4); 

lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
lcd.print("ESTRUCTURAS DE DATOS");
lcd.setCursor(9,1);
lcd.print("Y");
lcd.setCursor(5,2);
lcd.print("ALGORITMOS");
delay(1800);   //tiempo de espera 1.8 segundos
lcd.clear();

lcd.setCursor(2,0);
lcd.print("DEPARTAMENTO DE");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("MECATRONICA AGRICOLA");
lcd.setCursor(7,2);
lcd.print("5to 5");
lcd.setCursor(0,3);
lcd.print("Prof. Castellanos L.");
delay(2500);
lcd.clear();

lcd.setCursor(4,0);
lcd.print("Integrantes:");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print(" ");
lcd.setCursor(4,2);
lcd.print("Gomez G. Gil");
lcd.setCursor(3,3);
lcd.print("Ruiz C. Brayan");
delay(2000);
lcd.clear();

if(a == NULL){
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("No hay espacio en la memoria");
  delay(1500);
  free(a);
}

c = (int *)a;
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Ingresa un número");
char pulso = teclado1.getKey();
if(pulso != 0){
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(pulso);
  num = pulso;
  c[i] = num;
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("Guardado");
  delay(1500);
  lcd.clear();
  }
}
void loop(char pulso, char num, int i, int *c, void *a, void *b) {
int y;
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Quieres ingresar mas");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("números?");
lcd.setCursor(3,2);
lcd.print("Si = 1  No = 0");
if(pulso != 0){
  y = pulso;
}
if(y == 1){
   agrega(pulso, num, 1, c, a, b);
} 
if(y == 0){
   libera(c, a, b, i);
}
else{
  lcd.setCursor(3,1);
  lcd.print("Sigue bien las");
  lcd.setCursor(3,2);
  lcd.print("instrucciones");
  delay(1500);
  lcd.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: Hay algún error antes de ése?  Por ejemplo :main.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `clrscr'                       
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status "

Answer (score 3):

Un sketch Arduino tiene que ajustarse al siguiente formato:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Primer problema: falta el `loop()` que requiere Arduino.

Un sketch Arduino tiene que tener esas dos funciones. La función `setup()` es llamada una vez, al iniciarse el microcontrolador.

La función `loop()` es llamada luego en un ciclo eterno. En cada pasada por esta función debe ser tan corta como sea posible; el excesivo uso de `delay()` dentro de la función puede conducir a otro tipo de problemas (perdida de datos en comunicaciones, por ejemplo).

En Arduino no puedes programar a la manera tradicional: desplegar un menú, pedir una entrada, hacer algo, etc. Eso tienes que dividirlo en etapas individuales, atómicas, y ejecutar sólo una ellas en cada pasada de loop. Por supuesto, necesitas recordar donde estabas.

Para ilustrar el punto, hagamos un programa que pida dos enteros positivos por `Serial` y luego imprima la suma.

El `setup` no tiene complicaciones:

```
enum etapas {menu, ingreso1, ingreso2};
enum etapas etapa;

int valor1;
int valor2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  etapa = menu;
}
```

La variable `etapa` nos dice en que punto del proceso nos encontramos (desplegar el menú, pedir primer valor, pedir segundo e imprimir).

Los dos valores a sumar los almacenamos en `valor1` y `valor2`. Estamos usando variables globales para poder conservar sus valores entre cada llamada a `loop`.

Ahora `loop` es simplemente un `switch` que pregunta en que etapa estamos y actua en consecuencia.

```
void loop() {
  switch (etapa) {
    case menu:
      Serial.println("Programa de Suma:");
      Serial.print("Ingrese primer valor: ");
      etapa = ingreso1;
      break;
    case ingreso1:
      if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        valor1 = Serial.parseInt();
        if (valor1) {
          etapa = ingreso2;
          Serial.println(valor1);
          Serial.print("Ingrese segundo valor: ");
        }
      }
      break;
    case ingreso2:
      if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        valor2 = Serial.parseInt();
        if (valor2) {
          Serial.println(valor2);
          Serial.println(valor1 + valor2);
          etapa = menu;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

En la primera pasada `etapa = menu`, por lo que se imprime el título del programa y el prompt para pedir el primer valor. Se avanza la variable `etapa = ingreso1` y se termina la iteración.

En la siguiente iteración `etapa = ingreso1`, por lo que toca pedir el valor. El problema es que eso puede tomar cualquier tiempo, y en Arduino **ninguna llamada bloquea**: cuando una operación no puede realizar de inmediato, se retorna indicando la situación.

En el caso de `Serial.parseInt()`, si no hay un valor entero disponible, la función falla después de un *time-out* configurable. En caso de falla, retorna cero.

Para evitar *timeout* inútiles, primero chequeamos que haya al menos un caracter pendiente por leer usando `Serial.available()`.

Después de obtener un entero positivo (> 0), el `case ingreso1:` imprime el prompt para el segundo valor y avanza `etapa = ingreso2:`, donde se pide el segundo valor, se imprime la suma y se reinicia `etapa = menu` para repetir todo el proceso.

#### Demo

[image: Ejecución programa suma dos numeros]

Comment: candid Moe, wow, no sabía eso... pense que era como en C++ que solo imprimias y era todo jeje, voy comprendiendo lo que me escribes, empezando por el loop ya voy mal entonces jeje. Voy a corregirlo, de verdad muchas muchas gracias por explicarme  todo esto de arduino 