# ¿Cómo hago que Arduino espere a que ingrese un dato?

Tags: arduino

Al estar usando un keypad con un arduino y una LCD me he enredado completo. El punto del programa es ingresar datos a través de un Keypad y acumularlos en un puntero. Trato de hacer que, al pulsar un botón del keyPad, el dato de ese botón se guarde en un puntero y después se vayan agregando más y más datos. Tengo casi listo el programa pero no logro hacerlo esperar a que se apriete un botón del keyPad.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 10, en = 11, d4 = 12, d5 = 13, d6 = 14, d7 = 15;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs,en,d4,d5,d6,d7);

const byte Filas = 4;
const byte Columnas = 4;
byte pines_filas[] = {9,8,7,6};
byte pines_columnas[] = {5,4,3,2};
char teclas [Filas][Columnas] =
{
  {'7','8','9','/'},
  {'4','5','6','x'},
  {'1','2','3','-'},
  {'C','0','=','+'}
};

Keypad teclado1 = Keypad(makeKeymap(teclas),pines_filas,pines_columnas,4,4);

void *a = NULL;
void *b = NULL;
char *c = NULL;

void guarda(int i, char pulso, char *c){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Dato ");
  lcd.print(i);
  lcd.print(" = ");
  for(int m=0; m<i; m++){
    c[m] = pulso;
    lcd.print(c[m]);
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Guardado");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Ingresar mas datos?");
  lcd.setCursor(3,1);
  lcd.print("Si = 9  No = 0");
}

void agrega(int i, char pulso1, char *c){
  i = i+1;
  b = realloc(c, i * sizeof(char));
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Dato ");
  lcd.print(i);
  lcd.print(" = ");
  for(int n=i-1; n<i; n++){
    c[n] = pulso1;
    lcd.print(c[n]);
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Guardado");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
}
void setup(){
  lcd.begin(20,4); 
  lcd.setCursor(2,0);
  lcd.print("Porfavor ingresa");
  lcd.setCursor(6,1);
  lcd.print("un dato:");
  lcd.setCursor(3,3);
}
void loop() {
  int s = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int i = 1;
  a = malloc(i * sizeof(char));
  c = (char *)a;
  char pulso = teclado1.getKey();
  char pulso1 = teclado1.getKey();
  if(pulso != 0){
    guarda(i, pulso, c);
    s = s+1;
  }
  while(s > 0){
    char pulso = teclado1.getKey();
    if(pulso != 0){
      switch(pulso){
        case '9':
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Ingresa un numero");
            /*¿como hago que el programa espere y 
            detecte a la variable "pulso 1"*/
          agrega(i, pulso1, *c);
          break;
        case '0':
          lcd.clear();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Arduino tiene 2KB RAM. Esos son 2.000 bytes para todas tus variables, stack y demases. En Arduino no se usa `malloc`, `realloc` ni nada parecido: tienes que reservar y administrar el espacio disponible a mano. Es decir, si quieres ingresar algo por teclado, tienes que tener reservado el espacio máximo que vas a usar. Mi recomendación es que reescribas el programa eliminando la memoria dinámica.

Comment: Respecto a tu actual pregunta, tu `loop()` está totalmente incorrecto. Como se explica en la respuesta a tu anterior pregunta, debes procesar por partes, una pequeña cosa en cada pasada de loop. En Arduino **NO** puedes esperar ni detenerte dentro de `loop()`. Por favor, revisa bien https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497618/c%c3%b3mo-procesar-teclados-en-arduino

Comment: Vale, comprendo, disculpa, está bien, de verdad muchas gracias, lo de la memoria dinámica, creo que lo entiendo, muchas gracias Candid Moe